# Bootstrap columns act like rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to generate an Invoice from `HTML`. The problem is that I need three equal columns on the header on different widths, but for some reason the items from the header appears in rows. I'm using bootstrap.

Even if I add these lines of code to my snippet, it appears like rows. Can you please advise what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

```html
@model GGISServices.Models.TimberMonitor.GenerateDamageInvoiceViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <title>Damage</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapstyle")
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .font-bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .background-grey {
            background-color: #eaeaea;
        }

        .full-border-row td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }

        .column h1, h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .logo {
            height: 40px;
            width: 250px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .headerData {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10.75pt;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .ownerText {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: normal;
        }

        .companyHeaderData, .partnerHeaderData {
            line-height: 8px;
        }

        .invoiceData {
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .invoicePNP {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .invoiceData p {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .signs {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .descriptionText {
            margin-left: 5px !important;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .column {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            margin-right: 100px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container headerData">
        
        <div class="row" style="height:15px;"></div>
      
             <div class="row">                 
                    <div class="column companyHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Furnizor:</p>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Company.CompanyName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Company.CompanyRegistryNumber</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Company.CompanyCIF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column invoiceData col-sm-3" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 style="text-align: center;"> INVOICE </h2>
                            <br />
                            <p class="invoicePNP" style="text-align: center;"> @Model.CompanyPNPPrefix   @Model.CompanyPNCurrentNumber </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column partnerHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Partner.PartnerName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Partner.PartnerNrReg</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Partner.PartnerCIF</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The columns wrap because your row is to small to fit all 3 columns next to eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear in rows, because they don't fit the parent row and they change when the screen width gets under 768px. Remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right` to fit the parent.

And maybe change the `-sm-` to `-xs-` if you want them after each other on every screen width.

```html
@model GGISServices.Models.TimberMonitor.GenerateDamageInvoiceViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <title>Damage</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapstyle")
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .font-bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .background-grey {
            background-color: #eaeaea;
        }

        .full-border-row td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }

        .column h1, h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .logo {
            height: 40px;
            width: 250px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .headerData {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10.75pt;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .ownerText {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: normal;
        }

        .companyHeaderData, .partnerHeaderData {
            line-height: 8px;
        }

        .invoiceData {
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .invoicePNP {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .invoiceData p {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .signs {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .descriptionText {
            margin-left: 5px !important;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .column {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container headerData">
        
        <div class="row" style="height:15px;"></div>
      
             <div class="row">                 
                    <div class="column companyHeaderData col-xs-4">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Furnizor:</p>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Company.CompanyName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Company.CompanyRegistryNumber</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Company.CompanyCIF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column invoiceData col-xs-4" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 style="text-align: center;"> INVOICE </h2>
                            <br />
                            <p class="invoicePNP" style="text-align: center;"> @Model.CompanyPNPPrefix   @Model.CompanyPNCurrentNumber </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column partnerHeaderData col-xs-4">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Partner.PartnerName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Partner.PartnerNrReg</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Partner.PartnerCIF</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working this way on my machine. Thanks, But the strange thing is that I have copied to the test environment, and there it appears like rows, although I have copied the right file.

Comment: Maybe it has someting to do with some CSS we're not seeing here?

Answer (score 0):

```html
@model GGISServices.Models.TimberMonitor.GenerateDamageInvoiceViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <title>Damage</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapstyle")
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .font-bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .background-grey {
            background-color: #eaeaea;
        }

        .full-border-row td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }

        .column h1, h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .logo {
            height: 40px;
            width: 250px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .headerData {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10.75pt;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .ownerText {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: normal;
        }

        .companyHeaderData, .partnerHeaderData {
            line-height: 8px;
        }

        .invoiceData {
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .invoicePNP {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .invoiceData p {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .signs {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .descriptionText {
            margin-left: 5px !important;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .column {
            border: 1px solid grey;

            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container headerData">

        <div class="row" style="height:15px;"></div>

             <div class="row">                 
                    <div class="column companyHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Furnizor:</p>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Company.CompanyName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Company.CompanyRegistryNumber</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Company.CompanyCIF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column invoiceData col-sm-3" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

                            <h2 style="text-align: center;"> INVOICE </h2>
                            <br />
                            <p class="invoicePNP" style="text-align: center;"> @Model.CompanyPNPPrefix   @Model.CompanyPNCurrentNumber </p>


                    </div>

                    <div class="column partnerHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Partner.PartnerName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Partner.PartnerNrReg</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Partner.PartnerCIF</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />

</body>
</html>
```

```html
@model GGISServices.Models.TimberMonitor.GenerateDamageInvoiceViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <title>Damage</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapstyle")
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .font-bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .background-grey {
            background-color: #eaeaea;
        }

        .full-border-row td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        }

        .column h1, h2 {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .logo {
            height: 40px;
            width: 250px;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        .headerData {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 10.75pt;
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .ownerText {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: normal;
        }

        .companyHeaderData, .partnerHeaderData {
            line-height: 8px;
        }

        .invoiceData {
            line-height: 12px;
        }

        .invoicePNP {
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .invoiceData p {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .signs {
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .descriptionText {
            margin-left: 5px !important;
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .column {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            margin-right: 100px;
            margin-left: 50px;
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container headerData">

        <div class="row" style="height:15px;"></div>

             <div class="row">                 
                    <div class="column companyHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">Furnizor:</p>

                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Company.CompanyName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Company.CompanyRegistryNumber</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Company.CompanyCIF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column invoiceData col-sm-3" style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 style="text-align: center;"> INVOICE </h2>
                            <br />
                            <p class="invoicePNP" style="text-align: center;"> @Model.CompanyPNPPrefix   @Model.CompanyPNCurrentNumber </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column partnerHeaderData col-sm-3">
                        <p style="font-weight:bold;">@Model.Partner.PartnerName</p>
                        <p>Reg.Com: @Model.Partner.PartnerNrReg</p>
                        <p>C.I.F.: @Model.Partner.PartnerCIF</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />

</body>
</html>
```